# Error message "Start PXE over IPv6 -- Start PXE over IPv4 -- PXE-E18 server responce timeout"

Tags: boot, pxe

When I restart my Dell(INSPIRON 3421) PC, it is showing this message :

Start PXE over IPv4 -- PXE-E18 server response timeout,Start PXE over IPv6.

Now PC takes 4/5 minutes for successful booting.

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 4):

This is occurring as in BIOS network boot option is enabled and in boot priorities network boot is 1st or before to the option USB or primary HDD.

You simply need to disable network boot option in BIOS setup of your Dell INSPIRON 3421.